# JetBrains IDE Error on start : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: windows, runtime-error, runtime, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have got this error, but hardly could find the solution after 2 times reinstalling my IDE and even I installed 'All in One runtimes' but it couldn't help since I think the problem originally started after I changed few settings in windows defender setting and then tried to reset them.

But sure others have reported this problem and had no idea of what had happend all of a sudden to get following error when trying to run the application:

JetBrains IDE Error on start : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

[The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYnxW.png)
*1 - which in my case was Phpstorm64.exe running on windows 10

I just felt there is no 'easy to find' solution for this occurring problem, so I decided to post it on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 10):

In my case this was helpful and worked for me:

> > just disable ASLR (Address space layout randomization) from windows defender

in Windows 10 you should follow these steps:

1. open Settings (just right-click on windows start and choose
   settings)
2. search for 'Windows Defender Settings' or just go to 'Update & Security' > 'Windows Security'
3. then open 'App & browser control', in the new opened window scroll down to the end to find 'Exploit protection settings', click
   that
4. sort of settings will be shown and you can change the default settings.  to create an exception you should click "Program settings"
   (which doesn't seem to be a button,but it is!)
5. click 'add program to customize', in the dialog enter your ide name.exe  (you can easily find it by clicking 'open file location' on
   shortcut of the application)

   - in my case the application name was 'phpstorm64.exe'
6. next you have to look for 'force randomization for images (Mandatory ASLR)' check the 'override system settings' and switch it off and apply settings.

   - I'm not sure if it's needed,but turning off 'Randomize memory allocations (Bottom-up ASLR)' stated to work for others

I would appreciate if you help to get a complete solution for this problem , thanks

Comment: Worked for me on AndroidStudio. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The crash is probably caused by ASLR Windows feature, the relevant ticket in the JetBrains issue tracker: [IDEA-184029](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184029)

Please check if the following workaround:

*Turn the feature off globally or for a specific executable path https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/customize-exploit-protection*

helps