# Android Studio opening error: Unable to Start Correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: android-studio, runtime-error

I just installed `Android.Studio.3.4.1.0.x64` but when I want to open it, I get this error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK
>   to close the application.

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

I searched for the error and did these things but didn't work:

1. Reinstalled the AndroidStudio
2. Installed dot net framework 4.7.2 developer pack
3. Installed latest version of DirextX
4. Restarted my computer each time of above steps

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found the following answer here [JetBrains IDE Error on start : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795155/jetbrains-ide-error-on-start-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0x?rq=1) from @Amir Karamat, and it worked for me:

> in Windows 10 you should follow these steps:
>
> 1. open Settings (just right-click on windows start and choose
>      settings)
> 2. search for 'Windows Defender Settings' or just go to 'Update & Security' > 'Windows Security'
> 3. then open 'App & browser control', in the new opened window scroll down to the end to find 'Exploit protection settings', click
>      that
> 4. sort of settings will be shown and you can change the default settings.  to create an exception you should click "Program settings"
>      (which doesn't seem to be a button,but it is!)
> 5. click 'add program to customize', in the dialog enter your ide name.exe  (you can easily find it by clicking 'open file location' on
>      shortcut of the application)
>
>    - in my case the application name was 'phpstorm64.exe'
> 6. next you have to look for 'force randomization for images (Mandatory ASLR)' check the 'override system settings' and switch it
>      off and apply settings.
>
>    - I'm not sure if it's needed,but turning off 'Randomize memory allocations (Bottom-up ASLR)' stated to work for others

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But keep in mind that you have to give the name of the app in the Program Files folder. Not the .exe you have downloaded.

Comment: That's worked for me.Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, I almost wasted 2 hours looking for the solution. :)

Comment: Thank you @user3486308. I had this Problem with Android Studio 2021.2.1 in Windows 11 too and it was solved with the solution provided by you. My problem was solved well without doing the last step.