# Unable to start Android Studio (3.5.3) on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

After I installing Android Studio(3.5.3) on Windows 10 and opening it for the first time, I receive error popup saying "The application was unable to start correctly"

Screenshot attached here

[image: Application unable to start popup]

Comment: Your windows and Android Studio are both 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio opening error: Unable to Start Correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536708/android-studio-opening-error-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install C++ libraries for Windows. You can find it [here for 32 bits](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=5555) and [here for 64 bits](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=14632). Also sometimes it can be for the missing of [DirectX](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109).