# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 application error on startup

Tags: ssms

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqp0X.png)
[[image]]

I just install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 and the window pop up with
"Ssms.exe - Application Error"
"the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

I tried most of the solution found on Google and YouTube.
(Window Update, reinstall .net framework, .net runtime, microsoft visual c++ redistributable package, use admin to run program, re-install and repair Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18)

I will be really appreciated it.

UPDATE: [Solved] I use dependency Walker to find out which dll is crushing the program (in my case mscvr120.dll) and re-download it to fix the crush.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio opening error: Unable to Start Correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536708/android-studio-opening-error-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

Comment: Still get error

Comment: You might try to get the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16,   or if that fails too, from https://aka.ms/ssmsfullsetup